# Can ocelot be used to combine angular app and apis or it is only suitable for routing apis?

Tags: asp.net-core, reverse-proxy, api-gateway, ocelot

I am using Ocelot - API gateway for .NET Core
https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot

Scenario:

I have the following sites

- Ocelot API Gateway .NET Core
- Site A - Angular app
- Site B - .net core API
- Site C - .net core API

Now what I want is all request should first reach ocelot from there it will redirect to respective app and APIs

Request first goes to Ocelot from there routing should take place as mentioned below

```
/ -  route to the angular app (Site A )
/b - route to API (Site B)
/c - route to API (Site C)
```

I am able to route to /b and /c to respective API and app. Just need to know is ocelot suitable for routing to App like I have used Angular here or it is designed for routing apis in microservices. What are its pros and cons if angular app is used

Comment: Maybe same question in "https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot/issues/606" kebin suggestion is to use it with routes "https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot/issues/606#issuecomment-420239778", so with your ocelot is your entry point and redirect to site A, B and C, I'm in the same problem studing for now

Answer (score 0):

I'v did something similar, following your example, it should be some like this:

- Ocelot API Gateway .NET Core  ----> (http://entrypoint.com)
- Site A - Angular app          ----> (http://localhost:5001/)
- Site B - .net core API        ----> (http://localhost:5002/b)
- Site C - .net core API        ----> (http://localhost:5003/c)

Configuracion in ocelot project:

```
{
    "ReRoutes": [
        {
        "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/b/{everything}",
        "DownstreamScheme": "http",
        "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
            {
                "Host": "localhost",
                "Port": 5002
            }
        ],
        "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/b/{everything}",
        "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get","Post" ]
        },
        {
        "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/c/{everything}",
        "DownstreamScheme": "http",
        "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
            {
                "Host": "localhost",
                "Port": 5003
            }
        ],
        "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/c/{everything}",
        "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get","Post" ]
        },
        {
        "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/{everything}",
        "DownstreamScheme": "http",
        "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
            {
                "Host": "localhost",
                "Port": 5001
            }
        ],
        "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/{everything}",
        "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get","Post" ]
        }
    ],
    "GlobalConfiguration": {
        "BaseUrl": "https://entrypointurl.com"
    }
}
```

Ref:

- Ocelot Getting Started

https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/gettingstarted.html

- Ocelot Routing

https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/routing.html

Comment: I found proxy kit will better suits this scenario https://github.com/proxykit/ProxyKit

Ocelot is for api gateway but the proxy kit is reverse proxy